# Descomprimir una carpeta desde java

Tags: java

Necesito descomprimir una carpeta desde java sin embargo no me funciona la clase

```
package controlador;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;  
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class Descomprime {  
       public void Descomprimir (String c, String d )throws Exception{

    ZipInputStream entrada = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(c)));
    if(entrada.getNextEntry()==null)
    {
        int leido;
        byte []buffer = new byte [4758];
        BufferedOutputStream salida = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(d),4758);
        while((leido = entrada.read(buffer, 0, 4758))!=1)
            salida.write(buffer, 0, leido);
            salida.flush();
            salida.close();
            entrada.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Me arroja un error en la linea

```
BufferedOutputStream salida = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(d),4758);
    while((leido = entrada.read(buffer, 0, 4758))!=1)
    introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: Te falta abrir una llave luego del `while ( .... ) {`.

Comment: También después agregar la llave al while te faltaría una llave '}' para cerrar la clase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas confundiendo el flujo Zip (ZipInputStream) con las entradas (ZipEntry).
Lo correcto sería guardarse el entry en una variable y actuar cuando es distinto a null, no cuando es igual :

```
    ZipInputStream flujo = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                             new FileInputStream(c)));
    ZipEntry entrada = flujo.getNextEntry();
    if ( entrada != null) {
```

En la línea :

```
while ((leido = entrada.read(buffer, 0, 4758)) != 1)
```

[entrada.read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)) devuelve el número de bytes leidos o -1 si se ha llegado al final de la entrada. Cuando devuelve -1 esto provoca la excepción en la línea :

```
            salida.write(buffer, 0, leido);
```

al pedir que escriba -1 bytes.

Lo correcto sería comparar que no es -1 :

```
while ((leido = entrada.read(buffer, 0, 4758)) != -1)
```

También hay que tener en cuenta que un ZIP puede contener carpetas además de archivos. No podemos simplemente tratar todas las entries como si fuesen archivos.

```
        if (entrada.isDirectory()) {
            File directorio = new File(nombreSalida);
            directorio.mkdir();
        }
```

Finalmente, un ZIP puede contener varios archivos (entradas o entries), con lo que no basta un if, hay que recorrerlos en un bucle para obtener todos los archivos y descomprimirlos. El siguiente es el código completo :

```
package controlador;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class Descomprime {

  public void Descomprimir(String ficheroZip, String directorioSalida)
          throws Exception {
    final int TAM_BUFFER = 4096;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[TAM_BUFFER];

    ZipInputStream flujo = null;
    try {
      flujo = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
              new FileInputStream(ficheroZip)));
      ZipEntry entrada;
      while ((entrada = flujo.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        String nombreSalida = directorioSalida + File.separator
                + entrada.getName();
        if (entrada.isDirectory()) {
          File directorio = new File(nombreSalida);
          directorio.mkdir();
        } else {
          BufferedOutputStream salida = null;
          try {
            int leido;
            salida = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(nombreSalida), TAM_BUFFER);
            while ((leido = flujo.read(buffer, 0, TAM_BUFFER)) != -1) {
              salida.write(buffer, 0, leido);
            }
          } finally {
            if (salida != null) {
              salida.close();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } finally {
      if (flujo != null) {
        flujo.close();
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Me he tomado la libertad de cambiar el tamaño del buffer por un número redondo (en binario). Pero independientemente del número usado no es recomendable repetirlo por varios sitios del código, mejor definir una constante y utilizar esa constante en el código.

Comment: cuanto lo ejecuto y lo debug no ingresa en la condicion `while ((entrada = flujo.getNextEntry()) != null) ` le estoy pasando la ruta de entrada, el zip contiene dos carpetas y dentro de las carpetas hay dos imagenes

Comment: la ruta que le paso donde esrta el zip es Y:\casaentrada\Lote012016083056.zip y donde descomprime Y:\casaentrada\Lote012016083056

Comment: En su momento lo probé y ahora lo he vuelto a probar y funciona bien. ¿Es posible que le hayas pasado la ruta "Y:\casaentrada\Lote012016083056.zip"? en ese caso está mal porque \ es para secuencias de escape. Debes usar "Y:\\casaentrada\\Lote012016083056.zip" y lo mismo en la otra ruta.

Comment: realmente asi esta con el \\ o de lo contrario lo toma como error

Comment: Pues no se que problema puedes tener. ¿Qué sistema operativo usas? ¿Qúe te devuelve java -version? ¿Puedes meter todo tu código en un archivo descargable, poniendo también el Lote012016083056.zip con que haces las pruebas y subirlo a algún sitio desde el que me lo pueda descargar? O si es un archivo que no puedes subir por ser confidencial sube otro que hagas tu y en que se produzca el mismo fallo.

Comment: Para mi funciono perfectamente, gracias.